# architecture arm64 missing in libm?

Tags: c, makefile, apple-m1, libm

I have ported a small tool from Linux to MacOS on x86 using simply the existing Makefile. Now, I need to build a universal app, since some users have got M1 hardware.

I have followed Apple's instructions on building a universal app, and have add a new target to my Makefile:

> gcc -g -o arm -target arm64-apple-macos10.12 ar.o -lm

However, ld complains that arm 64 is missing is in /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/usr/lib/libm.tbd.

Any ideas?

Please do not suggest to use Xcode as another part of the project is using flex and bison and other folks have reported bugs in Xcode when using these two.